# What is SSL, TLS, and SSL/TLS?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, tls1.0

I want to know what is ssl and TLS. Someone in Internet are saying ssl is renamed as TLS both are same. Someone says both are different both are different protocols. I have read one more article that using of ssl and tls will give more security I.e SSL/TLS. I am confusing what is the exact one ?

Comment: See also [What's the difference between SSL, TLS, and HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/whats-the-difference-between-ssl-tls-and-https)

Answer (score 1):

SSL/TLS is a broad topic, and the question is not so specific. Nevertheless, here you can find basic information:  https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/ssl-vs-tls-difference/

Essentially, TLS is a better and upgraded version of SSL, and should be used instead of SSL versions.

Comment: Ok what is ssl/ tls ? I am seeing that in many places

Comment: I would advise reading the basics on the same. Some references:- 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security    ,
https://www.websecurity.symantec.com/security-topics/what-is-ssl-tls-https    ,
https://www.instantssl.com/ssl.html    ,
https://www.thesslstore.in/new-to-ssl/what-is-ssl-tls.aspx